# Django: ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que PasswordResetView trabaje con ajax?

Tags: ajax, json, django

estoy implementando a una pequeña web la posibilidad de recuperar sus contraseña mediante la clase **django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView**, como soy totalmente nuevo en este framework aun no puedo entender como funcionan las clases y métodos.
**Lo que deseo** es que a través de ajax jquery poder enviar el email del formulario a la clase y así enviar el correo al usuario con el link de recuperación. 
**El problema** es que cuando envío el formulario con ajax mediante el método POST no envía el correo, pero SI valida el formulario, y cuando lo hago sin ajax si envía el formulario.

Este es mi forms.py (Como pueden ver he implementado el método clean_email para verificar si el email esta registrado)

```
class FormResetEmail(PasswordResetForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        fields = ['email']

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if not Usuario.objects.filter(email__iexact=email, is_active=True).exists():
            msg = "There is no user registered with the specified E-Mail address."
            self.add_error('email', msg) 
            return email
```

Este es mi views.py, AQUÍ, quiero que vean que he "descubierto" que cuando envío el formulario de manera no asíncrona (sin ajax) el email se envía pero para eso debo descomentar el *`success_url = reverse_lazy('home')`*

```
class ResetPasswordCandidato(PasswordResetView):
        model = Usuario
        #template_name = 'modals/modal-login.html'
        form_class = PasswordResetForm
        email_template_name = 'email/reset_password_email.html'
        subject_template_name = 'email/password_reset_subject.txt'
        #success_url = reverse_lazy('home')


        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            form =  self.form_class(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid:
                return JsonResponse({'email': 'send'})
            else:
                return JsonResponse(form.errors)
```

Mi intención es devolver un json con el estado de la acción, si se envío me devuelva un {'email':'send} de lo contrario me retorne el error que en el forms.py he agregado.

Disculpen mi ignorancia, reconozco que lo estoy haciendo de la peor manera, pero quiero saber si ¿existe algún método que se ejecute cuando la acción (el envió del correo) se ha ejecutado?.

Estás son mi urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('sign_up', RegistrarCandidato.as_view(), name='registrodeusuario'),
    path('login_user', LoginCandidato.as_view(), name='iniciodesesion'),
    path('send_reset_password', ResetPasswordCandidato.as_view(), name='send_reset_password_candidato'),
    path('reset_password/<uidb64>/<token>/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('log_out', UsuarioLogOut, name='cerrarsesion'),
]
```

por último este es mi ajax

```
$(document).on('submit', '#validate-restaurar', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* Act on the event */
    let validate =  validateForm("#validate-restaurar")
    let action = $(this).attr('action');
    let data = $(this).serialize();
    if(validate){

  /*AjaxData, es una función que que devuelve un callback, con el error y la respuesta de la petición*/
            AjaxData(action, data, function(e,r) {
                console.log('AQUI ERROR DJANGO2', e)
                console.log('AQUI RESPUESTA DJANGO2', r)
            })
    }
});
```

Comment: Dices que cuando descomentas `success_url`manda el mail. Te regresa el json o te manda a la vista 'home'?. Creo que deberías implementar tu propio `form_valid` ya que este metodo te manda a `success_url`.

Comment: @loki digo que solo funciona cuando está el success_url pero no puedo usar succes_url en una petición ajax porque no espero me redireccione, más bien quiero que me devuelva un json con el estado de la operación.

Comment: Cabe aclarar que si me devuelve el json porqué si ingresa al def post y además si valida el formulario, pero se queda allí nomas, no envía el correo, a diferencia de cuando lo hago sin ajax y con el success_url activo, allí se dirección y si envia el correo